# CSS3 animation can't back to 0% normally in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I had a CSS3 animation in my page. It works well until it backs to 0% or 100%.

It doesn't return, instead it flies up!

And this only happens in Chrome, not in Firefox.

```
        @keyframes my-right{
            50%{
                -moz-transform-origin:right;
                -webkit-transform-origin:right;
                transform-origin:right;
                -moz-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
                -webkit-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
                transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
            }
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style type="text/css">
        .basic{
            position: absolute;
            width: 48px;
            height: 48px;
            background: #FF2200;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid black;
            -moz-transition: height 1s linear;
            -webkit-transition: height 1s linear;
            transition: height 1s linear;
        }
        #right{
            top:100px;
            left:150px;
            -moz-animation:my-right 10s linear infinite;
            -webkit-animation:my-right 10s linear infinite;
            animation:my-right 10s linear infinite;
            z-index: 100;
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes my-right{
            50%{
                -moz-transform-origin:right;
                -webkit-transform-origin:right;
                transform-origin:right;
                -moz-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
                -webkit-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
                transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
            }
        }
        @keyframes my-right{
            50%{
                -moz-transform-origin:right;
                -webkit-transform-origin:right;
                transform-origin:right;
                -moz-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
                -webkit-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
                transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
            }
        }
    </style>
    <div id="right" class="basic">right</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the 100%? make it come back.

Comment: there is no 100%, so I thing it should return to 0%, isn't it?

Comment: 50% alone will make the animation stuck at 50%.. you should include 100% too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did make a 100% keyframe to it get back to its original place:

```css
.basic {
  position: absolute;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #FF2200;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-transition: height 5s linear;
  -webkit-transition: height 5s linear;
  transition: height 5s linear;
}

#right {
  top:100px;
  left:150px;
  -moz-animation:my-right 5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation:my-right 5s linear infinite;
  animation:my-right 5s linear infinite;
  z-index: 100;
}

@-webkit-keyframes my-right {
  50% {
    -moz-transform-origin:right;
    -webkit-transform-origin:right;
    -moz-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);                
  }
       
  100% {
    -moz-transform-origin:right;
    -webkit-transform-origin:right;
    -moz-transform:perspective(1000px) translateX(-46px) translateZ(-50px) rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(0px) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg);                
  }      
}

@keyframes my-right {
  50% {
    transform-origin:right;
    transform:perspective(0px) translateX(46px) translateZ(50px) rotateY(180deg);
  }
          
  100% {
    transform-origin:right;
    transform:perspective(0px) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px) rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="right" class="basic">right</div>
```

Comment: yeah, it works! But why is that, do we always need to write 100% or just in this case?

Comment: i dont know if it is valid in css animation syntax but, in a general way, 50 percent means half part of the total which means there's something missing;